# i get an error when trying to build a tableView in swift for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

HI I watch many tutorials to finally create an app for the app store.Recently I got interested by tableViews so I followed many tutorials and I seem to always get an error whereas the people in the tutorial succeed to build their app .
When I try to run my app , the building stops and I get an exception in the AppDelegate class on the line where it says "class AppDelegate ..." the exception is "Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT"

and for those interested here is the message in the console .

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'must pass a class of kind UITableViewHeaderFooterView'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c80f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b7c4bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c80e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010a5fb254 -[UITableView registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:] + 247
    4   tableviewtes                        0x0000000109a9cc3c _TFC12tableviewtes14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 460
    5   tableviewtes                        0x0000000109a9ccd2 _TToFC12tableviewtes14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a631a90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a631c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a550ca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a551041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a55d72c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a508061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a50ad2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a509bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d3512a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bb653c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bac285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bac045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bab486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010a509669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010a50c420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21  tableviewtes                        0x0000000109a9faee top_level_code + 78
    22  tableviewtes                        0x0000000109a9fb2a main + 42
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bf9e145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Run the app with the "All Exceptions" breakpoint and show us where in the code the exception occurs.

Comment: The console message appears to describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - the class that you passed to `registerClass:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:` is not a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` - check where you call this method and the definition of the class you are passing

Answer (score 40):

Probably the function you want to use is

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewController.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

instead of

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewController.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

Hope that's it ...

Answer (score 11):

I think its a tiny mistake.

Instead of :

```
tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

You need to use:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Please note that the first argument in register function should be `UITableViewCell` NOT `UITableView`

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I too suffered from this problem.

As Paulw11 said, the problem is your register class method call.

I followed a pull to refresh tutorial and got the table view working like this:

I replaced

```
    var tableView = tableViewController.tableView

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewController.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

with:

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("sortArray"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl

...

func sortArray() {
    ...
}
```

enabling pull to refresh and allowing my code to run.